# Maximum number of PasswordCredential in PasswordVault UWP

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I didn't find any information on the online documentation that provide the allowed number of PasswordCredential Object that can be stored in Windows PasswordVault. Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **Remarks** of [PasswordVault.Add | add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701231)

> You can only store up to ten credentials per app in the Credential Locker. If you try to store more than ten credentials, you will encounter an [Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.exception).

So the maximum number of `PasswordCredential` in `PasswordVault` is **10**.